# Extract chars enclosed in complex brackets within a string in most efficient way

Tags: javascript, regex, string, performance

I have a string in which there are brackets, and in brackets could be another brackets. For example:

```
var string1 = "1 a (C(b(c+ d)e-fg)) 3# 4df (h j) 5 6 ((k))";
```

Every open bracket is closed, but not necessarily immediately, meaning, inside a bracket could be another bracket. Chars, digits and other signs like + - # $ % (excluding '!") can be all over the string, grouped or solo.

What I want is to extract every char from brackets (regardless if it is numeral, letter, sign...), and format those chars separated with one blank space, including that if there are chars that go immediately one after another, like "c+" or "e-fg" in example, they would be grouped together. In above example, result would be:

```
var string2 = "C b c+ d e-fg h j k";
```

I have this code that does this:

```
var string1 = '1 a (C(b(c+ d)e-fg)) 3# 4df (h j) 5 6 ((k))';
var opens = new Array();
opens.push(string1.indexOf('('));
string1 = string1.replace('(','!')
var closes = new Array();
var done = false;
while (!done) {
    openindex = string1.indexOf('(');
    closeindex = string1.indexOf(')');
    string1 = string1.replace(')','!').replace('(','!');
    if (openindex>closeindex) {
        opens.push(openindex);
        closes.push(closeindex);
    }
    if (string1.indexOf(')')==-1) {
        closes.push(closeindex);
        done = true;
    }
}
var string2 = '';
for (var i=0;i<opens.length;i++) string2 = string2 + string1.substring(opens[i],closes[i]);
string2 = string2.replace(/!!/g,'  ').replace(/!/g,' ').replace(/  /g,' ');
```

This works (https://jsfiddle.net/nL2gp80j/1/), but I am looking for more efficient solution. I don't know regex, and maybe this could be acomplished much better and faster with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much shorter and better way to achieve desired result without involving regular expressions a lot more:

```js
str = '1 a (C(b(c+ d)e-fg)) 3# 4df (h j) 5 6 ((k))';
array = [], counter = 0;

str.split(/([()])/).filter(Boolean).forEach(function(e, i, a) {
    // Increase / decrease counter and push desired values to an array
    e == '(' ? counter++ : e == ')' ? counter-- : counter > 0 ? array.push(e) : true;
    if (i === a.length - 1)
     // Join all values with a whitespace between
 console.log(array.join(' '));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for double checking previously accepted solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex `/[^a-z]*/ig` it will replace everything other than char

```js
var string1 = "1 2 (a(b(c d)efg)) 3 4 (h j) 5 6 ((k))";
string1 = string1.match(/[a-z]+/ig);
string1=string1.join(" ");
console.log(string1);
```

[Edited from comment @Jai]

Comment: No, string is mixed, chars are not only within brackets. As I wrote in the question, I only used digits for better visual. In real scenario, chars and other signs like + - $ % etc are all over the string.

Comment: This will eleiminate alle brackets and spaces, it returns: abcdefghjk. But he wants the spaces too.

Comment: @HenryP Instead of negating better accept and extract with `.match()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to extract the letters with grouping. Use `String.prototype.match()` method with a regular expression as an argument for this:

```js
var str = "1 2 (a(b(c d)efg)) 3 4 (h j) 5 6 ((k))";
var ex = str.match(/([a-z])+/g); // will give you grouped letters
console.log(ex.join(" ")); // and join it with a space.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, if ensured that the brackets are in the right adjustment.

```
var string1 = "1 2 (a(b(c d)efg)) 3 4 (h j) 5 6 ((k))";
string1 = string1.replace(/[\(\)]*/ig,'');
alert(string1);
```

Note: I edited the replace-string beacause there was a copy-paste error.

Comment: I don't know if this is close. The problem is that chars are not only within brackets, all types of chars are all over the string in real case scenario, as I explained in the question. I only separated digits and chars for easier visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a simple way to do it in only one regex, but this does the job:

```js
    var string1 = "1 a (C(b(c+ d)e-fg)) 3# 4df (h j) 5 6 ((k))";
    // remove before the first (
    string1 = string1.replace(/^[^()]*\(/, '(');
    // reome after the last )
    string1 = string1.replace(/\)[^()]*$/g, ')');
    // remove outside parenthesis
    string1 = string1.replace(/\)[^()]+\(/g, ')(');
    // while there is at least one (
    while (string1.indexOf('(') != -1) {
        // remove pair of parenthesis
        string1 = string1.replace(/\(([^()]+)\)/g, " $1 ");
    }
    // remove superfluous spaces
    string1 = string1.replace(/ +/g, ' ');
    console.log(string1);
```

Comment: Great, that's it, a regex solution. Is this faster than original code?

Comment: This wouldn't be right if string would be `1 a (C(b(c+ d)e-fg(test))) 3# 4df (h j) 5 6 ((k))`